# Changing structure of 2d numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a numpy array named my_array

When I print `glove_ds.shape`, I get 2049
When I print `glove_ds[i].shape`, I get 300 (i is within the range of 2049)

I want to change glove_ds shape to 2049*300 (when I call the `glove_ds.shape`). How should I do that?

So my code is:

```
print(glove_ds.shape, glove_ds[0].shape)
```

And the answer is

```
> (2429,) (300,)
```

I want the answer to be

> (2429*300)

Comment: can you post a minimal example? shapes are typically given as tuples, therefore it is diffficult to answer your question if you only specify integer values

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: Do you have a numpy array? Or did you create an array with object datatypes? Or are you talking about an xarray dataset, since you call it ds?

Comment: I want to create a dataset which I want to be a 2d dataset. Number of raws = number of samples, number of columns = number of features

Comment: The issue clearly is where `glove_ds` is initialized/generated. Without these code parts, it is very hard to pinpoint the problem. I would bet that you mix datatypes somewhere, e.g. by trying to initialize a numpy array with a list of tensorfow tensors - which would explain why both have a `.shape` function.

Comment: Try `np.stack(glkve_ds)`

Comment: From the shapes and comments, this appears to be a 1d object dtype array.  If all the element arrays have the same shape, than `stack` or another `concatenate` should be able to join them into one array.  But if they do differ in shape, that will raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

how did you create the Array glove_ds? You should not use "dtype=object".
And is the length of every glove_ds[i] the same?

Comment: You're asking for additional informations in an answer. Please write a comment for that, before answering the question.

Comment: Yes it is the same

Comment: try to print the datatye of glove_ds[i] if it's array or list

Answer (score -1):

What about `my_array.size` - it returns the total number of elements in your array https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-ndarray-ndim-shape-size/, or does it have to be printed as a multiple between 2 numbers? Then `my_array.shape` and `my_array.len` can be used

Comment: As stated in the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html), `my_array.size` is the same as `np.prod(my_array.shape)` with a different datatype.

Comment: Exactly? I.e if OP wants the total number of elements in the array, then `size` is the way to go. It is unclear, however, if OP wants the *results* of the calculation or to print it like the calculation e.g if OP wants `15` to be printed or `3*5`